# Terminal columns, an unnecessary(!) max width limit set in 16.04?

Tags: command-line, unity

CTRL+ALT+T  and then
Menu: Edit > Profile Preferences > gives you this dialog:
[image: Terminal settings; 160 columns]

NOTE: This defines the INITIAL size of the Terminal window.

With this settings (which is similar to what I used in 14.04) doesn't make the terminal be 160 columns, but in Terminal 3.18.3 I see:

```
Linux wkbx 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:39 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux           
.bash_aliases executed in 0 seconds. tty has 113/64 columns/lines.
```

Note the last sentence, as output from.

```
echo "tty has $(tput cols)/$(tput lines) columns/lines."
```

NOTE: *I have no trouble resizing* but wish to have it way larger without the "mouse fiddling".
No setting above 113 is obeyed - I wish for a remedy.
Is there REALLY a legitimate REASON for the limit?

Whatever I google turns up non-relevant info, I'm out of ideas.

---

Dragging out for a larger window,

```
$ echo "tty has $(tput cols)/$(tput lines) columns/lines."
tty has 213/64 columns/lines.
```

maximizing window

```
$ echo "tty has $(tput cols)/$(tput lines) columns/lines."
tty has 283/83 columns/lines.
```

and smaller again

```
$ echo "tty has $(tput cols)/$(tput lines) columns/lines."
tty has 96/34 columns/lines.
```

Comment: Is your terminal window itself more than 113 columns?

Comment: Nope, it comes up sized as indicated by the text above. 113 columns *max*, regardless of what I change "160" to (larger than 112).

Comment: Correction. I mean the window of the emulator itself, not the size defined in settings.

Comment: The window is 113 columns max.

Comment: Not to invalidate your question, just an observation: on my 16.10 I get the results you expected.

Comment: Let me rephrase. What are the results of your command if you drag the corner of your terminal window to make it bigger?

Comment: Added above....

Comment: So, it is the initial size; how it comes up as it starts that doesn't match the setting. No other trouble.

Comment: @guntbert, 16.10 is not LTS and additionally "server" oriented, so I'd rather not "update"

Comment: @Hannu of course not - I didn't suggest anything here.